# Why can't my class access its own privately declared variable of another object

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error

```
game.cpp:19:35: error: ‘Player Game::p1’ is private within this context
   19 |  Point playerMove = tictactoeGame.p1.makeMove();
      |                                   ^~
In file included from game.cpp:1:
game.hpp:12:10: note: declared private here
   12 |   Player p1;
```

Followed by 3 errors of the same exact situation with the other variables. I thought I could access these members as they were a part of the Game object.

Here is my class I am referring to

```cpp
// game.hpp

#ifndef GAME
#define GAME

// Includes
#include "player.hpp"
#include "board.hpp"
  
class Game
{ 
    private:
        Board gameboard;
        Player p1;
        Player p2;
    public:
        Game(Board& gb, Player& p1, Player& p2);
        bool checkWinner(); // Determine if their is a winner or tie, or if the game is still going.
        void announceResults(int winner); // Announce the winner and end the game.
        bool checkMoveValidity(const Point& sector); // Check if the players move is a valid move.
};
  
#endif


//game.cpp

#include "game.hpp"

Game::Game(Board& gb, Player& p1, Player& p2) : gameboard{gb},p1{p1},p2{p2} {}

// Some functions that were implemented

// Main to test out some functions
int main()
{
    Board tictactoeBoard;
    Player x('x',"Caleb");
    Player o('o',"Caleb2");
    Game tictactoeGame(tictactoeBoard, x, o); 

    Point playerMove = tictactoeGame.p1.makeMove(); ///// Error here
    while(true)
    {
        if(tictactoeGame.checkMoveValidity(playerMove))
        {
            tictactoeGame.gameboard.placePiece(playerMove,tictactoeGame.p1); ///// Error here
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid move. Please enter a valid move.";
            playerMove = tictactoeGame.p1.makeMove(); ///// Error here
        }
    }

}
```

Also, here are the members as defined in `player.hpp` and `board.hpp`

```cpp
//player.hpp
class Player
{
    private:
        char symbol;
        std::string name;
    public:
        //////
}

//board.hpp
class Board
{
    private:
        std::array<std::array<char,3>,3> board;
    public:
        int rows;
        int cols;
}
```

Although these objects also have private attributes, I thought they would be accessible within the game class.

Do I need to make `Game` a friend in both of these classes, or would that break encapsulation?

Comment: Is the line of code `Point playerMove = tictactoeGame.p1.makeMove();` inside the class of `Game`?  If not, then since it is private, you can't access it.

Comment: did you expect that you can "access it" in `main` because you wrote `tictoactoeGame.p1` while you would expect to have "no access" when writing just `p1` ? You seem to misunderstand how member access restriction works, so I am trying to find out what the misunderstanding is

Comment: @idclev463035818 I was expecting to have access to `.p1.makeMove()` as `p1` was a member variable of my `game`. However, as you pointed out, I could not do that because I was trying to do all of this from main, instead of creating a function where I could then have access to all of these internals.  I since moved the logic that was in my main into a function and it is executing as expected, and as it should. Thank you for helping to bring some clarity to this for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, the lines of code causing the error are within the `main` function, which, as a standalone function, cannot access private variables of the class. Only methods of the class can access private variables.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I, for one, consider it to be slightly rude to post an answer based on a comment without pointing out that the idea is not mine.

Comment: I was following the guidance at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok, actually I am on your side. Credits to whom credits due.

Comment: no worries you did everything correct. Forget my comment.

Comment: I would have gone looking for a duplicate. There has to be at least one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat actually sometimes my answer is just compilation of comments put into some text. I have to admit that I not always refer to the comments in such case. Reading the meta now to learn something ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I admit that I don't always do this either, and it matters more when comments had some important ideas, and not in simple Q&As like this one.

Comment: I see. My mistake. Thank you for pointing this out to me.